# Javascript. How to call a method inside an object property of the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

This might seem confusing (or not), but it's been boggling my mind.
So I have a class property of type object **hospot**, which was basically declared:

```
Cannon.prototype.hotspot = {stuff: this.blah(...) };
```

Now the **bla()** method is actually a prototype of the 'class' as well.

```
Cannon.prototype.blah = function() { ... };
```

Now I have a problem wherein it says that the method blah() is not existent, I'm assuming it's because the '*this'* pertains to the context of the object *hotspot* and not the **Cannon** 'class'. Now what I'm wondering is how can I call the method  **blah()**?

By the way I've tried replacing **this.blah()** with this:

```
Cannon.prototype.blah.call(this, ...);
```

But there is a new problem. It says that some variables in the method is undefined. Now the method has variable like *this.x* which the class absolutely have and is defined, it's just not picking it up for some reason.

Help guys. :) Thanks

Comment: The problem is the fact this is in the window scope when you are creating it, it is not in the scope of Cannon.

Comment: Did you run `var obj = new Cannon()` and run `obj.hotspot()` instead of running `Cannon.prototype.hotspot()`

Answer (score 0):

Thera are two objects: Cannon and Hotspot. Because "{..}" on "Cannon.prototype.hotspot" is an object creation literal.

You need to separate them:

```
function Cannon(hotspot) {
    if ( hotspot.constructor == Hotspot ) {
        this.hotspot = hotspot;
        // this.hotspot = new Hotspot();
        this.hotspot.setCannon(this);
    } else {
        throw "type mismatch: hotspot"
    }
}
// Less Flexible Constructor
// No need to pass "Hotspot" object
// function Cannon() {
//     this.hotspot = new Hotspot();
//     this.hotspot.setCannon(this);
// }

Cannon.prototype.blah = function(a){
    alert("Hello "+a);
};

function Hotspot() {
    this.cannon = null;
}
Hotspot.prototype.setCannon = function(cannon){
    if ( cannon.constructor == Cannon ) {
        this.cannon = cannon;
    } else {
        throw "type mismatch: cannon"
    }
};
Hotspot.prototype.stuff = function(a){
    if ( this.cannon ) {
        this.cannon.blah(a);
    }
};
```

You can test this:

```
var hotspot = new Hotspot();
var aCannon = new Cannon(hotspot);
aCannon.hotspot.stuff("World");
```

or

```
var aCannon = new Cannon( new Hotspot() );
aCannon.hotspot.stuff("World");
```